# What is the definition of subgradient in words?

Tags: definition, subgradient

I am trying to understand the meaning of subgradient precisely.
Is the subgradient of a function at point $x$, any linear underestimator of a function that touches the function in only at $x$?

Do you know a more elegant way of putting it?

Comment: Think of it as a hyperplane that separates the point $(x,f(x))$ from the rest of the epigraph.

Comment: Epigraph is still too technical for this purpose.

Comment: Replace epigraph by graph :-).